# Simple ring is actually an algebra over a field

Tags: abstract-algebra

I heard that every simple ring can be seen as an algebra over a field. What are those corresponding field and algebra over it?

I thought a while, but I have no idea yet about what they should be.

Comment: From Wikipedia: “ The center of a simple ring is necessarily a field. It follows that a simple ring is an associative algebra over this field. So, simple algebra and simple ring are synonym.” https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_ring?wprov=sfti1

Comment: @ThomasAndrews Is the fact about the center being a field trivial?

Answer (score 1):

From [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Simple_ring?wprov=sfti1):

> The center of a simple ring is necessarily a field. It follows that a simple ring is an associative algebra over this field.

This is pretty easy to prove.

It is easy to see that the center contains $0,1$ and is a subring.

If $r\neq 0$ is in the center, then $rR$ is a non-zero two-sided ideal of $R,$ so, by the definition of a simple ring, $rR=R.$ In particularly, $1\in rR,$ or $r$ is a unit.

It is not hard to seem that $r^{-1}$ is also in the center. Because:

$$r^{-1}s=r^{-1}srr^{-1}=r^{-1}rs r^{-1}=sr^{-1}$$

So the center is a field.

Comment: Thank you! I'm new working with algebras.